# Unable to read complete yaml file from perl script

Tags: perl

how do i read the below yaml file from perl script ?

test.yaml

```
---
a: first
b: second
c: third
---
a: fourth
b: fifth
c: seventh
```

I have tried the below script, but no luck

```
use YAML;
use Data::Dumper;

open (YFILE, "<test.yaml") or die $!;
my $yaml = join('', <YFILE>);
close(YFILE)

my $hash = YAML::Load($yaml);

print Dumper($hash);
```

Please suggest.

Comment: It's shown in the synopsis of the module: [YAML](http://p3rl.org/YAML)

Comment: @choroba I didn't even know about that. +1.

Comment: It's important to give information about what doesn't work.  "No luck" doesn't tell us what went wrong.  With the program you show above, you would have received a syntax error at line 8.  You need to tell us what those errors are to help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: Please select the correct answer with a checkmark.

Comment: @beta0x64: Neither did I. Therefore, I googled for "yaml three dashes perl".

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should enable `use strict` and `use warnings`.

You're also missing a semi-colon on your `close(YFILE)`.

When I add a semi-colon to your script, I get this output:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'c' => 'seventh',
      'a' => 'fourth',
      'b' => 'fifth'
};
```

Thanks to @choroba, you can apparently do this:

```
use YAML;
use Data::Dumper;

open (YFILE, "<test.yaml") or die $!; 
my $yaml = join('', <YFILE>);
close(YFILE);

my (@objs)  = YAML::Load($yaml);

print Dumper(@objs);
```

Which returns:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'c' => 'third',
      'a' => 'first',
      'b' => 'second'
};

$VAR2 = {
      'c' => 'seventh',
      'a' => 'fourth',
      'b' => 'fifth'
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response

I have updated the script as suggested, but i couldn't get the first group

is there any way to get complete (both) groups